# d3 axis cut-off Horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]When I run my code the x and y-axis labels get cut off, and the bar chart ends prematurely. Any ideas how to rectify this. I imagine it has something to do with getting the range of the data to draw the SVG.I attached a copy of the image so you can see

```
var format = d3.format(",.0f");

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], .1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(-h),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
.attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

d3.csv("t.csv", function(data) {

  // Parse numbers, and sort by value.
  data.forEach(function(d) { d.value = +d.count; });
  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.count; });

  // Set the scale domain.
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.primary_type; }));

  var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.primary_type) + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

  bar.append("text")
  .attr("class", "value")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
  .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
  .attr("dx", -3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return format(d.value); });

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.primary_type; }));` should be `y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.primary_type; }));`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work any ideas?

Comment: `.attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");` this translate the full graph give a higher m[3]